# Trouble setting up a search for a single field

Tags: 7, search

I am trying to set up a search that will only search a single field of a single content type. I am currently using search api with database search server module. I set up the search to index only this one field and a bundle filter that only returns results from the specified content type. The problem I am running into is the results.

If I set the field type to integer (it is a zip code I am searching through), it returns every search result regardless of if it contains the integer or not. If I set it to fulltext, it doesn't return anything regardless if i type an exact match to one of the fields it is indexing.

Am I setting this up right? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Better way to do this would be using Views and the built-in Filters. Exposing those filters will make it searchable.

Comment: Can give a quick walk through? Not really sure what you mean. The user has to be able to input a number and the site will spit back the closest result.

Comment: Install Views. Go to structure>views then Add new view. Show [content] of type [Your Content type here] (also tick Create a page) then Continue & edit button. Under FORMAT select Show: Fields. Then under FIELDS click Add button and add the fields you want to show in the result. Then click Add button next to FILTER CRITERIA and add your zip-code field. On the settings screen of that field tick "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it". Hope you can take it from there.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me. That is SOOOOO much easier and it actually works. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Added as answer in case anyone else has same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Views.

1. Install Views.
2. Go to Structure>Views then `+ Add new view`.
3. Set `Show [content] of type [Your Content type here]` (also tick Create a page) then Continue & edit button.
4. Under FORMAT select Show: Fields. Then under FIELDS click Add button and add the fields you want to show in the result. Then click Add button next to FILTER CRITERIA and add your zip-code field. On the settings screen of that field tick "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it".