# Partial searches through exposed filters in views

Tags: 7, views, search

So this is an extension of a question I asked earlier today: [Trouble setting up a search for a single field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60037/trouble-setting-up-a-search-for-a-single-field)

To save you some reading, I have a client that wants to put a bunch of distributors in as a custom content type and have the user use a search function and find the closest distributor based on one field, their zip code. Each dealer has a number of zip code prefixes that they service. For example, a distributor that services 999 will service zips 99901, 99902, and so on. Through using views and exposed filters, the search works if they put in the first 3 numbers. But if they try to put in more, it breaks and doesn't return anything.

These prefixes are stored in one field like so: 111, 112, 113, and so on. How can I get views to only look at the first 3 numbers if they put in their full zip code or is there some other way to get this to work?

Comment: Why don't you use the geofield and geocoder modules to geocode the info in your zipccode field, then give your users an exposed proximity search filter to allow them to define the proximity distance to them and punch in their zipcode? The approach you are suggesting above seems like your duct taping something together, rather than leverage some awesome modules that will make a better user experience.

Comment: They want it to mirror the old system that used sql queries and other things. Things that today would be considered duct tape. After a few hours of researching, it looks like I am going to have to do this the hard way. From scratch.

Comment: Gotcha. You could be up and running in several minutes the other way I was suggesting